# How do you set select=false for a nested Mongoose document?

Tags: javascript, mongoose

This is my User schema:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  profile: {
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    role: String
  },
  auth: {
    hashedPassword: { type: String, required: true },
    facebookToken: String,
    twitterToken: String,
    googleToken: String
  },
});
```

I want to set `select = false` for the whole `auth` object. How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply add it this way:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  profile: {
    username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    role: String
  },
  auth: {
    type : {
      hashedPassword: { type: String, required: true },
      facebookToken: String,
      twitterToken: String,
      googleToken: String
    },
    select: false //<---- added here
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I confirmed with [this code](https://gist.github.com/adamzerner/f7007d03a18c8dff0223).

Comment: When I store type Number in auth.type schema it store number value as a string.Can you help me out for this issue.